# efficient tidy R technique for processing aligned data frame groups

Tags: r, dataframe, tidyverse

I'm trying to find an efficient (and ideally tidy) way to process a pair of grouped data_frames. The setup looks more-or-less like this:

```
A = crossing(idx=1:1e5, asdf=seq(1:rpois(1,50))
B = tbl(idx=sample(1:1e5, replace=TRUE), yet_more_stuff='whatever')
proc_one_group <- function(one_A, one_b) { ... }
# example:
proc_one_group(filter(A, idx==50), filter(B, idx==50))
```

So, my processing operation, which is fairly complex, operates on one `idx` at a time, from two separate data frames, where one of them has one or more (usually dozens) rows per `idx`, and the other can have zero, one, or multiple rows per `idx`.

A way I know I can do this is this, but it's very slow, because the `filter` operation on every value requires a full table scan and subset.

```
map_df(unique(A$idx), ~ proc_one_group(filter(A, idx==.), filter(B, idx==.)))
```

I also know I can use `split` to create a list of subframes of data_frames relatively efficiently, but I don't know a good way to then do O(1) lookups by index of the two `data_frame`s.

What I sort of want is the first step of a `left_join`, where it figures out the subgroups of indexes from each group, but instead of actually creating a single `data_frame` of the cartesian combination of each group, it just gives me the pair of subgroups that I can process as needed. (A full `left_join` doesn't help me here.)

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One possibility would be to nest your two data frames first, before joining:

```r
library(tidyverse)

set.seed(1234)

A = crossing(idx = 1:1e5, asdf = seq(1:rpois(1, 50)))
B = data_frame(idx = sample(1:1e5, replace = TRUE), yet_more_stuff = "whatever")

proc_one_group <- function(one_A, one_B) { ... }

nest_A <- A %>%
  group_by(idx) %>%
  nest(.key = "data_a")
nest_B <- B %>%
  group_by(idx) %>%
  nest(.key = "data_b")

all_data <- full_join(nest_A, nest_B, by = "idx")
all_data
#> # A tibble: 100,000 x 3
#>      idx            data_a           data_b
#>    <int>            <list>           <list>
#>  1     1 <tibble [41 x 1]>           <NULL>
#>  2     2 <tibble [41 x 1]> <tibble [2 x 1]>
#>  3     3 <tibble [41 x 1]> <tibble [2 x 1]>
#>  4     4 <tibble [41 x 1]> <tibble [1 x 1]>
#>  5     5 <tibble [41 x 1]>           <NULL>
#>  6     6 <tibble [41 x 1]>           <NULL>
#>  7     7 <tibble [41 x 1]> <tibble [2 x 1]>
#>  8     8 <tibble [41 x 1]>           <NULL>
#>  9     9 <tibble [41 x 1]> <tibble [1 x 1]>
#> 10    10 <tibble [41 x 1]> <tibble [1 x 1]>
#> # ... with 99,990 more rows
```

This results in a single data frame, with the data for each `idx` from data frame `A` in `data_a`, and the data from data frame `B` in `data_b`. Once this is done, the large data frame don't have to be filtered for each case in the `map_df` call.

```r
all_data %>%
  map2_df(data_a, data_b, proc_one_group)
```

Comment: Oh, very clever. Yes, this does the matching part of the join, without actually doing the join.

Answer (score 2):

Here's some benchmarking results:

```
A = crossing(idx=1:1e3, asdf=seq(1:rpois(1,50)))
B = tibble(idx=sample(1:1e3, replace=TRUE), yet_more_stuff='whatever')
```

The first idea is to use `split` as you suggested, keeping the order of `split.A` and `split.B` the same. You can use `map2` to iterate through the matched lists:

```
myfun <- function(A,B) {
    split.A <- split(A, A$idx)
    splitsort.A <- split.A[order(names(split.A))]
    splitsort.B <- map(names(splitsort.A), ~B[as.character(B$idx) == .x,])
    ans <- map2(splitsort.A, splitsort.B, ~unique(.x$idx) == unique(.y$idx))
    return(ans)
}
```

This is the approach you are currently using, using `dplyr::filter`

```
OP <- function(A,B) {
    ans <- map(unique(A$idx), ~unique(filter(A, idx==.x)$idx) == unique(filter(B, idx==.x)$idx))
    return(ans)
}
```

This is the same logic but avoiding `dplyr::filter` which is *slower* compared to base R subsetting

```
OP2 <- function(A,B) {
    ans <- map(unique(A$idx), ~unique(A[A$idx==.x,]$idx) == unique(B[B$idx==.x,]$idx))
    return(ans)
}
```

This uses @JakeThompson's approach (it appears to be a winner among the current methods)

```
JT <- function(A,B) {
    nest.A <- A %>% group_by(idx) %>% nest()
    nest.B <- B %>% group_by(idx) %>% nest()
    ans <- full_join(nest.A, nest.B, by="idx")
}
```

Some validation to ensure that results of some of the functions make sense

```
identical(OP(A,B), OP2(A,B))
# TRUE

E <- myfun(A,B)
any(E==FALSE)
# NA

F <- myfun(A,B)
any(F==FALSE)
# NA

identical(sum(E==TRUE, na.rm=TRUE), sum(F==TRUE, na.rm=TRUE))
# TRUE
```

Benchmarking results

```
library(microbenchmark)
microbenchmark(myfun(A,B), OP(A,B), OP2(A,B), JT(A,B), times=2L)
# Unit: seconds
        # expr       min        lq      mean    median        uq       max neval
 # myfun(A, B)  3.164046  3.164046  3.254588  3.254588  3.345129  3.345129     2
    # OP(A, B) 14.926431 14.926431 15.053662 15.053662 15.180893 15.180893     2
   # OP2(A, B)  3.202414  3.202414  3.728423  3.728423  4.254432  4.254432     2
    # JT(A, B)  1.330278  1.330278  1.378241  1.378241  1.426203  1.426203     2
```